# What happens to AVAudioSession instance, if the iphone speaker is faulty/defective?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, avaudiosession

I would like to know answer for the following questions.

1) What happens if I try to play audio using AVAudioSession, where iphone speaker is faulty/defective/not working?

2) Is there any way, programatically check whether the speaker is working properly or its defective/faulty?
I would like to achieve this programatically not manually!

Please help or suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens with `avaudiosession` when speaker will faulty or defective. It will complete it's work in regular manner as it do if speaker is not faulty.

For example your speaker have fault that it unable to raise volume after some level or it becomes very slow for some reason then `avaudiosession` plays like usaul but volume level of output will be slow.

And you can't check this kind of stuff like speaker is faulty or not because fault can be of any type so there is no api or method that can identify hardware fault. You can check availability!

Comment: Thanks Lion.. Also would like to know if you have any idea about "LibSoX" and what is does??!!

Comment: You're welcome. No i don't have idea about `LibSoX`. You can ask separate question for that.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what defect it would be. If it is a defect that iOS cannot detect, then your code works as if the speaker was undamaged, there is no way to detect it, and the user will hear no sound or bad sound.

If it is a defect that iOS detects, then iOS may behave as if there was no speaker. (There were iOS devices without speakers in the past, and you can check what hardware is available).

On the other hand, I would assume that the user is either willing to live without sound, or is plugging in headphones or connecting a speaker via the headphone cable, or is going to repair the phone. It's not something that I would ever consider writing code for.